# Which DVCS is most conducive to experimenting?

Tags: dvcs

I was wondering which DVCS is most conducive to experimentation i.e. branching, etc. I want something where anyone can quickly launch smaller projects and refactor code quickly. I want to create an environment where experimenting is cheap and can be discarded/merged easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git is known for very cheap branching, they made it so that branching was something trivial, so that, like you said, you could create branches for any little thing. I don't have experience with the other DVCSes, but I imagine they're pretty similar given their similar nature. I just know that cheap branching is one of Git's reasons for creation, or something like that. Sorry if I misunderstood your question.

Here's a [section](http://whygitisbetterthanx.com/#cheap-local-branching) of a popular article/site giving details about git over other version control systems.

**In response to your comment**: On windows I imagine? I've been fine using [msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list), get [msysGit-fullinstall-1.6.4-preview20090729](http://msysgit.googlecode.com/files/msysGit-fullinstall-1.6.4-preview20090729.exe). For a detailed walkthrough with screenshots that helped out some friends, I recommend the [Git for Windows Developers](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jason_meridth/archive/2009/06/01/git-for-windows-developers-git-series-part-1.aspx) series.

Comment: That was my hunch as well, but I'm having a bitch of a time setting git.

Comment: as Linus said: "it's not about branching it's about merging" :)

Answer (score 2):

You could also try [Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/downloads/), it's fast, it's distributed and it's easier to use. If you like working with a GUI try -- [TortoiseHg](https://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/).

Here is an [analysis](http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/DVCSAnalysis) done by google before they integrated mercurial into google code.

Comment: We are running mercurial for .net programming for the past one year without any issues. Very stable and easy to use. Branching is easy in hg.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirements match Darcs or Git.

Answer (score 0):

If you're a GUI user, why don't you take a look at Plastic SCM? http://codicesoftware.blogspot.com/2010/03/distributed-development-for-windows.html. It's one of the few commercial DVCSs out there and it's focused on ease of use but it has all the features you're looking for:

- Excellent branching and merging support (full merge tracking, rename support and all that)
- Distributed (and easy to use)
- Subtractive merge support (you can do it from the GUI)

Besides:

- Very good visualization
- Excellent Windows GUI (check it)
- Excellent VStudio integration